# Why did my question get insta-locked?

Tags: discussion

Pretty simple. Asked a question: [What's a word to describe adding something unless it already exists, in which case I retrieve it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/570659/94742)

It got locked right away. Not even sure why. No comments are anything.

I'll gladly edit my question to make it fit the site, though locking first and commenting (maybe?) later seems a bit harsh. What can I do here?

Comment: It's still accepting answers, just not comments. Locking comments on single-word requests ensures you get answers people can vote up or down instead of comments that can only be up-voted. I think the down votes are because a portion of the community here doesn't really care for helping people name variables and functions in code. In general, code does things that people don't really need words for - Shakespeare had no need to write about someone looking for something then adding it if they couldn't find one.

Comment: It's pretty typical to use "get_or_create" or "get_or_add" for most languages, although new domain specific language for "get or create", like [upsert](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert) meaning "insert or update", may be evolving. If it is, it would be more likely to be known among software folks, not English experts.

Comment: The issue with naming functions is that you could just as well name your function *Susan* and it would work just as well. If you want an English word, you need to ask a question about English. [Here's one I prepared earlier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - LOL! *Susan.* The real world answer would be *banking.*